# UIImagePickerController is dismissing on didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

From Apple Documentation.
"This supports taking more than one picture without leaving the interface, but requires that you hide the default image picker controls".

On [self.imagePicker takePicture] the delegate didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo is being called but is still leaving the interface.
Any idea how can i prevent the controller from being dismissed?Here is my code of UIImagePickerController with custom overlay.

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
CameraOverlayView *overlay = (CameraOverlayView *)[self viewWithNibName:@"CameraOverlayView" owner:self];
overlay.frame = imagePicker.cameraOverlayView.frame;
imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = overlay;
overlay.imagePicker = imagePicker;
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
overlay = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem but i resolved this by using these classes in my code [UzysAssetsPickerController for iOS](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/uzysassetspickercontroller)

By using this i can select multiple images without dismissing the image picker. Hope this will help.

Comment: That is for picking multiple images.i am talking about taking multiple pictures here.

Comment: sorry m not getting you. Are you talking about take image from camera?? right?

Comment: By taking pictures i meant capturing multiple images with camera.Not just selecting from camera roll or saved albums.

Comment: yes, in this you can also click with camera by click on camera icon on the bottom of view. After click the picture that added to your library automatically with selection. Check out this functionality. May be this is useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem.Working perfectly now.Thank You everyone.

```
<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>
@property(nonatomic,strong) UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;
overlay.imagePicker = _imagePicker;
overlay.imagePicker.delegate = overlay;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 // may be it will help for you.
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
     // if you want to dismiss controll then use the following code
     [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

                }];
    // if you wnat to being present it comment the above dismis code
}
```